# Is it possible in the oracle to assign the result of the query which is in the CLUB variable with type varchar2?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a question about oracle, but I don't know if it's really possible to do it. I have a variable CLOB. In it request

```html
 SELECT (CASE WHEN 50 >  100 and tare = 'tare' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as test FROM dual
```

,
whether I can assign result of this request to any change with type varchar2 ??

At the exit I would like to have
some_var := sql_clob;
this functionality I would like to perform in processes!

Comment: Please share some more details. your question is not clear

Comment: @Tejash hi, i want to write a procedure in oracle. I want to use there functionality which will allow to write down in change with type varchar 2 result of inquiry. The query itself is in the table in the column with the format of the clob. In the example, I specified a query that is in a column with a clob format. The result of that query will be 0. I would like to assign this 0 to changes.

Comment: @Tejash But I don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: @Tejash i want to do something like "pl/sql function body returning sql query". There I would specify the procedure and return the query in clob format. In the report I would see the columns "test" and the value 0. I did it in apex oracle. And now I want to implement something similar in the procedure and assign the results to a variable. I hope you understand what I want to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that your query is:

```sql
SELECT (CASE WHEN 100 > 50 and dummy = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as test FROM dual
```

*(Since the `DUAL` table has one row containing a `DUMMY` column with the value of `X`.)*

Then you can use a cursor in a PL/SQL block to iterate over the result set:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql    CLOB := 'SELECT (CASE WHEN 100 > 50 and dummy = ''X'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as test FROM dual';
  v_value  VARCHAR2(50);
  v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;   
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cursor FOR v_sql;
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cursor INTO v_value;
    EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_value );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or, you could use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run the query:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql    CLOB := 'SELECT (CASE WHEN 100 > 50 and dummy = ''X'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as test FROM dual';
  v_value  VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_value;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_value );
END;
/
```

Both of which output:

> ```
> 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c97cc594e1c34828aacc3ee1ec966707)*